# where is old version of three.js? why new version of three.js is not compatible?

Tags: javascript, three.js

My app has problem with new version of three.js. where is old version of three.js? why new version of three.js is not compatible?

Answer (score 2):

> where is old version of three.js?

When using `npm`, you can install any previous version of `three.js`.

If you are including JS files directly into your project, you can download the build (and example) files for each release via GitHub links like:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r120

Just add the desired release at the end of the link.

> why new version of three.js is not compatible?

We are trying to minimize the occasions of breaking changes and keeping the engine backwards compatible as good as possible. But sometimes fundamental changes are required to move the engine forward.

Comment: You can also switch your tag in the github repo, and download the whole shebang as a zip, which is pretty much the same as downloading from the release.